# Getmonth(), Getday() and Getyear() not returning values

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

thanks for all your help so far! I really appreciate it, as i'm really struggling with Javascript.

Basically I'm building a date calculator when a user defined duration is added to a user defined date. I've got the date to appear fine, but it's in long format ("Wed Jan 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)), where as I want the return format to be 02 Jan 2013.I'm trying to break different bits of the date into separate variables, however when I run the script the variables dayFormatted, monthFormatted and yearFormatted are not displaying any value.

Any ideas?

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setExpDate(){

var formDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
var number = +document.getElementById('days').value;

// set number of days to add
var interval = number;

var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(formDate));
var expDate = startDate;
expDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);



 var monthFormatted  = expDate.getMonth();
 var dayFormatted  = expDate.getDay();
 var yearFormatted  = expDate.getYear();

 document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = monthFormatted;
 document.getElementById('daysdays').innerHTML = dayFormatted;
 document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = yearFormatted;
 };
 </script>
 </head>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" id="startDate" name="startDate" onblur="setExpDate(this.value)">

<select name="days" id="days" onchange="setExpDate(this.value)">
<option value="01">1</option>
<option value="02">2</option>
<option value="03">3</option>
<option value="04">4</option>
<option value="05">5</option>
<option value="06">6</option>
<option value="07">7</option>
</select>

 <div id="total"></div> <br/><div id="daysdays"></div><div id="year"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "*are not displaying any value*"? Have you tried to debug those variable, what value *do* they have?

Comment: It's [working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/EDz2K/) once you enter a valid date.

Comment: side note: `new Date(Date.parse(formDate))` is just a long way to write `new Date(formDate)` if `formDate` is a string. They use exactly the same parsing rules.

Comment: You are passing the values from the blur of startDate and the onchange of days but your function does not take a value. Call `setExpDate()` instead of `setExpDate(this.value)`. Also getYear is deprecated; you should use getFullYear() instead

Comment: It doesn't really affect this code the way it is, but something to be aware of, `var expDate = startDate;` is not copying the value of `startDate`, it is storing a reference to `startDate` in `expDate`. When you use `expDate.setDate()` it is also changing the value of `startDate`. If you want to make a copy of a date just pass the original date object into a `new Date()`, ie `var expDate = new Date(startDate);`.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've got it working. I'm a little puzzled though, when I transfer the script back to my page nothing shows up, but it works on jsfiddle... any idea why that maybe?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. Use browser developer tools like firebug or those built-in to firefox and chrome to add breakpoints in your javascript. Also you can use console.log to print debug statements.